# Minimizing CSS "margin-" rules to one "margin:" rule with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, arrays

I have entered each "margin-" CSS rule in an array giving me:

```
[ 'margin-left:15px', 'margin-right:25px', 'margin-top:100px' ]
```

I am trying to create an array that displays the values in the right order

```
var margRed1:[newMargTop, newMargRight, newMargBottom,newMargLeft];
```

My code is:

```
var directionRegex = /\d{2,3}px/;
var margRed = "margin: ";
var noMarg = "0px";
var margRed1 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < cssClassArrayMargin.length; i++) {
  if (cssClassArrayMargin[i].match('-top')) {
    var margTop = directionRegex.exec(cssClassArrayMargin[i]);
    var newMargTop = margTop[0];
  } else {
    newMargTop = noMarg
  }
  if (cssClassArrayMargin[i].match('-right')) {
    var margRight = directionRegex.exec(cssClassArrayMargin[i]);
    var newMargRight = margRight[0];
  } else {
    newMargRight = noMarg
  };
  if (cssClassArrayMargin[i].match('-bot')) {
    var margBot = directionRegex.exec(cssClassArrayMargin[i]);
    var newMargBot = margBot[0];
  } else {
    newMargBot = noMarg
  }
  if (cssClassArrayMargin[i].match('-left')) {
    var margLeft = directionRegex.exec(cssClassArrayMargin[i]);
    var newMargLeft = margLeft[0];
  } else {
    newMargLeft = noMarg
  }
}
if (newMargTop || newMargRight || newMargBot || newMargLeft === undefined) {
  newMargTop = noMarg;
  newMargBot = noMarg;
}

console.log(margRed1)
```

It gives me the following array:

```
  [ '100px', '25px', undefined, '15px' ]
```

I do not understand why it does not display 0px and instead displays undefined.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you try to initial this "margRed1" array like this first?

```
var margRed1 = [ '0px', '0px', '0px', '0px' ];
```

and then remove these code

```
if (newMargTop || newMargRight || newMargBot || newMargLeft === undefined) {
   newMargTop = noMarg;
   newMargBot = noMarg;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, setting the values at 0px by default was the best translation fo what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
[ 'margin-left:15px', 'margin-right:25px', 'margin-top:100px' ]
```

In the above code the entered value does not have all four value but in array there are four values

```
var margRed1:[newMargTop, newMargRight, newMargBottom,newMargLeft];
```

Give `margin-bottom:0` where you have entered the values like this

```
[ 'margin-left:15px', 'margin-right:25px', 'margin-top:100px', 'margin-bottom:0px' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about variable hoisting. You are declaring variables in blocks, which means they are hoisted to the top of the function and start their lives as undefined. This is very poor code:

```
if (someCondition) {
    var x = 0;
  } else {
    x = 1;
  }
```

It would be better written as:

```
var x;
...
x = someCondition ? 0 : 1;
```

Also the line:

```
if (newMargTop || newMargRight || newMargBot || newMargLeft === undefined) {
```

Is this intentional? You are testing for newMartTop, newMargRight, or newMartBot to be truthy, or newMargLeft to be undefined. You would be better to omit the `=== undefined` altogether.